# problema con un codigo en PHP y MySQL que me muestra los datos recolectados en PDF

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, pdf

Para empezar estoy empezando en el mundo de la programacion.

Estoy realizando un codigo en PHP y MySQL que me muestra los datos recolectados en PDF y me lo genera sin error.

Pero que pasa, a esa base de datos se le inserta informacion de un mismo municipio en varias veces lineas y el reporte me lo genera asi, y lo que necesito es que lo genere en una sola fila por municipio y me sume los valores de todas las columnas. Gracias de Antemano

[image: Reporte en PDF]

```
    <?php

require "conexion.php";
require "plantilla.php";

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $municipio = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['municipio']);

    $sqlmunicipio = "SELECT municipio FROM productos_despachados WHERE municipio = $municipio" ;
    $resultadomunicipio = $mysqli->query($sqlmunicipio);
    $row_municipio = $resultadomunicipio->fetch_assoc();
    $nombremunicipio = $row_municipio['municipio'];

    $tituloReporte = "Reporte de Productos Entregados por Municipios";

    $sqlmunicipio = "SELECT * FROM productos_despachados"; 
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sqlmunicipio);
    
    
    $pdf = new PDF("L", "mm", "letter");
    $pdf->SetTitle($tituloReporte);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Enrique Camaros');
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetMargins(15, 15, 15);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 9);

    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Municipio'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Pollo'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Pollo'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Picadillo'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Picadillo'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Salchicha'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Salchicha'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Aceite'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Aceite'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Detergente'), 1, 0, "C",0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode('% Detergente'), 1, 1, "C",0);
    
    $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 9);
    
      
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
    
    $i = $i + 1;
    
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['municipio'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['pollo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['Porc_pollo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['picadillo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['Porc_picadillo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['salchicha'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['Porc_salchicha'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['aceite'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['Porc_aceite'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['detergente'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $fila['Porc_detergente'], 1, 1, "C", 0);
        
}
     
    $pdf->Output('I', $tituloReporte . '.pdf');
}

?>
```

Comment: y que has intentado para hacer esa suma en una sola fila?

Comment: Ese es el problema donde estoy trabado. Que no se como por ejemplo sumar todos los datos de un solo municipio si estan en diferentes filas.

Comment: bueno eso es parte de la investigacion que debes hacer... si investigas e intentas hacerlo y tiene un error concreto que salga por pantalla hay nos dices para ayudarte... pero no podemos hacer un query de mysql sin conocer todas las partes de la base de datos que esta involucrado y eso solo lo sabes tu ahora mismo...

Comment: Acabo de hacer en MySQL una consulta con un municipio al azar y me salio como me hace falta. Ahora vere donde va en el codigo PHP.

Comment: debe de ir en donde haces la consulta ... de php a mysql.

Comment: SELECT 
SUM(Municipio)Lisa,(pollo)Pollo, (Porc_pollo)Porc_Pollo, (picadillo)picadillo, (Porc_picadillo)Porc_picadillo, (salchicha)salchicha, (Porc_salchicha)Porc_salchicha, (aceite)aceite, (Porc_aceite)Porc_aceite, (detergente)detergente, (Porc_detergente)Porc_detergente 
FROM productos_despachados where municipio='lisa';

Comment: si eso te trae los datos que necesitas entonces deberia sustituirlos por el query que genera los datos que no te funcionan...

Comment: Ahora revisando la consulta en el MySQL no me suma las columnas, solo me muestra el valor de la primera fila de cada columna.

Comment: entonces el query esta mal... lo importante es que hagas el query o lo intentes y si eso es lo que no te funciones, sea eso lo que preguntes ... no tiene nada que ver con meter eso en el PDF... lo del PDF es secundario... y se puede hacer mucho mas facil

Comment: Gracias. Como mencione soy nuevo en el tema de PHP y tambien soy nuevo aqui.

Comment: para eso estamos para ayudarte... pero parte de esa ayuda no tiene que ver con programacion directamente, si no para fortalecer la cultura de hacer debug, usar correctamente las herramientas y plantear correctamente nuestros problemas y dudas.

Comment: yo tambien soy nuevo ...

Comment: Estudia sobre sql, que es tu problema (ni php, ni nada).. tenes que hacer un sum de las columnas que queres y usar un group by. Es algo simple, pero implica que aprendas SQL.. como dijiste, estas recien empezando y nada mejor que empezar aprendiendo...

Comment: Gracias, Ya estoy en eso, tengo que hacer un GROUP BY de la columna municipio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que necesitas hacer es un segundo SQL con los operadores (SUMA, PROMEDIO, ETC) ya calculados para luego ponerlos en una fila y que no lo repite dentro de el while que tienes.

Aqui el codigo:

```php
<?php

require "conexion.php";
require "plantilla.php";

if (!empty($_POST)) {

    $municipio = mysqli_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['municipio']);

    $sqlmunicipio = "SELECT municipio FROM productos_despachados WHERE municipio = $municipio";
    $resultadomunicipio = $mysqli->query($sqlmunicipio);
    $row_municipio = $resultadomunicipio->fetch_assoc();
    $nombremunicipio = $row_municipio['municipio'];

    $tituloReporte = "Reporte de Productos Entregados por Municipios";

    $sqlmunicipio = "SELECT 
                        municipio, 
                        SUM(pollo) as total_pollo, 
                        AVG(Porc_pollo) as promedio_pollo,
                        SUM(picadillo) as total_picadillo, 
                        AVG(Porc_picadillo) as promedio_picadillo,
                        SUM(salchicha) as total_salchicha, 
                        AVG(Porc_salchicha) as promedio_salchicha,
                        SUM(aceite) as total_aceite, 
                        AVG(Porc_aceite) as promedio_aceite,
                        SUM(detergente) as total_detergente, 
                        AVG(Porc_detergente) as promedio_detergente
                    FROM productos_despachados 
                    WHERE municipio = $municipio";
    $resultado = $mysqli->query($sqlmunicipio);

    $pdf = new PDF("L", "mm", "letter");
    $pdf->SetTitle($tituloReporte);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Enrique Camaros');
    $pdf->AliasNbPages();
    $pdf->SetMargins(15, 15, 15);
    $pdf->AddPage();

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 9);

    // Encabezados
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Municipio'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Pollo'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Pollo'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Picadillo'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Picadillo'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Salchicha'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Salchicha'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Aceite'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(25, 5, utf8_decode('% Aceite'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(20, 5, utf8_decode('Detergente'), 1, 0, "C", 0);
    $pdf->Cell(30, 5, utf8_decode('% Detergente'), 1, 1, "C", 0);

    $pdf->SetFont("Arial", "B", 9);

    // Mostrar datos
    while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['municipio'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['total_pollo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['promedio_pollo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['total_picadillo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['promedio_picadillo'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['total_salchicha'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['promedio_salchicha'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['total_aceite'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(25, 5, $fila['promedio_aceite'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(20, 5, $fila['total_detergente'], 1, 0, "C", 0);
        $pdf->Cell(30, 5, $fila['promedio_detergente'], 1, 1, "C", 0);
    }

    $pdf->Output('I', $tituloReporte . '.pdf');
}

?>
```

IMPORTANTE: Estoy asumiendo que tus campos se llaman asi por los CELL que tienes, pero debes colocar los reales.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me ayudo mucho su respuesta, solo le agregue despues del WHERE municipio = $municipio" un GROUP BY municipio.  y quedo asi:          
                                                                                                                          
WHERE municipio = $municipio, GROUP BY municipio        y listo.